# How to get individual value from array using JavaScript/Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a array object which produce below output.

```
console.log('response',response);

response [{"id":"2","name":"subhra","pass":"12345","email":"subh@gmail.com"}]
```

Here i need all individual value(`email,id,pass,name`) using JavaScript.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you can simply store it in variable like var a=[{"id":"2","name":"subhra","pass":"12345","email":"subh@gmail.com"}]; then access it like console.log(a[0].id);

Comment: Please could you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: @ Ripun : No its showing undefined when i followed your way.

Comment: @CallumLinington : I have a object which output is given in my post.I need to extract all individual value from it and store in different variable.

Comment: Is your response a string?  You might need to call `JSON.parse(response)` and then use the methods suggested above.

Comment: @satya does your `response` array contain only one record ?

Comment: @satya can you please post your response as is what it is coming from browser

Comment: Got the answer .Its simple parse the value and access all individual value.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/ubq6E/)

```
var data=[{"id":"2","name":"subhra","pass":"12345","email":"subh@gmail.com"}];
console.log('response',data);

    console.log('response',data[0].id); //2
    console.log('response',data[0].name); //subhra
    console.log('response',data[0].pass); //12345
    console.log('response',data[0].email); //subh@gmail.com
```

Comment: first store array of object in one variable i.e data. check updated link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `angular.forEach`

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DyWPPwSXqszzHpsYnsFN?p=preview)

**Controller**

```
$scope.response = [{"id":"2","name":"subhra","pass":"12345","email":"subh@gmail.com"}]

angular.forEach($scope.response, function(item){
    $scope.Id = item.id; // id is in $scope.Id
    $scope.Name = item.name; // name is in $scope.Name
    $scope.Email = item.email; // email is in $scope.Email
    scope.Pass = item.pass;   // pass is in $scope.Pass
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p> ID : {{Id}}</p>
    <p> Name : {{Name}}</p>
    <p> Pass : {{Pass}}</p>
    <p> email : {{Email}}</p>
</body>
```